# Retornar último registro da tabela

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Estou tentando fazer uma um método que retorna o último registro da tabela, mas dá erro:

> Falha na operação"coditem"

```
   public int UltimoItem()
    {
        con = conexao.obterConexao();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Cod_Item) FROM Pedidos_Itens", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int Ultimo = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Ultimo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cod_Item"]);

            }
            return Ultimo;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Falha na operação: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: O campo `Cod_Item` existe?

Comment: Tenta colocar uma _alias_ para o retorno da função **MAX** e retornar esse mesmo nome no **Convert**

Comment: Dependendo da base de dados que você está utilizando, quando vc faz o "MAX" vc tem que dar um nome pra ele, assim "MAX(Cod_Item) AS Cod_Item" se não ele retorna a coluna sem nome, aí quando você tenta acessar o dr["Cod_Item"] ele não encontra a coluna e da erro. Veja se é esse o problema. É exatamente o que o @LeandroPaixão disse na resposta acima.

Comment: `SELECT Cod_Item FROM Pedidos_Itens order by Cod_Item desc limit 1`

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Leando falou, está aqui : `Ultimo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Cod_Item"]);`
Ao utilizar MAX você deve nomear esse campo para poder recuperá-lo.

Nesse casso creio que você poderia acessar posicionalmente utilizando a sintaxe
`Ultimo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);`, porém não é recomendável, que ao mudar seu SELECT, você pode se equivocar mudando a posição da coluna ao inserir uma nova ou alterando a estrutura do SELECT.

Tente:

```
public int UltimoItem()
    {
        con = conexao.obterConexao();
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Cod_Item) AS 'CodItem' FROM Pedidos_Itens", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int Ultimo = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Ultimo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CodItem"]);

            }
            return Ultimo;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Falha na operação: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uma pequena correção na sua resposta: 
    `Ultimo = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);`

Comment: Editei, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

É muito mais simples e eficiente que isto, basta ler com o método [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteScalar) que é o correto:

```
public int UltimoItem() {
    using (var con = conexao.obterConexao())
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Cod_Item) FROM Pedidos_Itens", con) {
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/ExecuteScalar.cs)

Aproveitei para tratar a liberação de recursos corretamente.

Retirei a exceção porque não está fazendo nada útil. Primeiro é um erro capturar `Exception`, é pior lançar outra `Exception`. Se não fez nada para se recuperar da exceção aí então deixe para tratar a exceção em outro lugar. Mas faça só em uma mais específica, no mínimo uma `SqlException`, talvez mais específica ainda. Não é obrigado tratar todas exceções, só o faça se puder fazer algo útil.

Comment: Me salvou esse `ExecuteScalar()`, estava utilizando o `ExecuteNonQuery()` só me retornava `-1`